# Remove multiple rows from table with a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [EF Code First Delete Batch From IQueryable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538899/ef-code-first-delete-batch-from-iqueryablet)

How can I remove multiple rows from table with a LINQ query.

I have code like:

```
var subjects = (from sub in db.Subjects select sub)
               .Where(sub => sub.title.StartsWith("ab"));
```

and I want to delete all these subjects from my table in one command like in sql:

```
"Delete FROM table WHERE ..."
```

Comment: Is this LINQ-to-SQL, LINQ-to-Entities...other? There's no built in method for doing that with either, but there are extension methods out there that will do this (but may have some unwanted side effects).

Comment: I asked a similar question a bit ago and got an informed response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538899/ef-code-first-delete-batch-from-iqueryablet

Answer (score 2):

You need a `loop` for that, you have to remove all the entities one by one, unfortunately there is no such feature as bulk delete either in Linq to SQL or in Entity Framework.

```
foreach(var subject in subjects)
{
    db.Subjects.Remove(subject);
}
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: No method to remove all togther?

Comment: I am sure about Entity Framework and Linq to SQL that there is no way using Linq, but you can execute any command using db.Execute() and you can write the deletion query there.

Comment: I dont want to use sql query.but its not efficient to remove one by one.